# Filter by IS NOT NULL AND in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two almost identical records. One that contains a null value for "Request ID" and the other one doesn't. I want to filter out the one that doesn't have a null value for that column but I am also looking to filter out the data based on a keyword.

> Ex:
> Search: ProjectName or Originator
>
> Result: *get the entry without the null "Request ID" value back*

Searching for the ProjectName gets me what I need but searching for Originator still gives me both results?

Here is what I have so far:

```
USE [ResourceRequest]
GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_project_bykeyword] 
(@ProjectName varchar(100)=NULL
,@Originator varchar(100)=NULL)
AS
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Resource_Request]
WHERE [Request ID] IS NOT NULL
AND 
[Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
OR [Originator] LIKE @Originator + '%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put parenthesis around this part, and you should be fine:

```
(
[Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
OR [Originator] LIKE @Originator + '%'
)
```

The reason for your problem was that the `OR` makes your filter true for any rows that match the `Originator` filter, regardless of the other filters, so the `[Request ID] IS NOT NULL` filter gets ignored as long as `[Originator] LIKE @Originator + '%'`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that. I'll go with your answer since you were first to respond. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 9):

[`AND` takes precedence over `OR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190276.aspx).  You should group your `AND` and `OR` statements:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     [dbo].[Resource_Request]
WHERE    [Request ID] IS NOT NULL
AND 
(
         [Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
     OR  [Originator]   LIKE @Originator + '%'
)
```

The reason for the grouping is due to the precedence order mentioned above.  This order is:

```
Level   Operators
1       ~ (Bitwise NOT)
2       * (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)
3       + (Positive), - (Negative), + (Add), (+ Concatenate), - (Subtract), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
4       =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, !>, !< (Comparison operators)
5       NOT
6       AND
7       ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, SOME
8       = (Assignment)
```

What this means is, all of your `AND` statements will be evaluated first.  After they have all been evaluated, *then* your `OR` statement is evaluated.

This makes your query look more like this to the compiler:

```
WHERE  
(   
       [Request ID] IS NOT NULL
   AND [Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
)
OR     [Originator] LIKE @Originator + '%'
```

Which isn't the clause you were looking for.

By grouping the `[Project Name]` and `[Originator]` segments of your `WHERE` clause, you are telling the compiler that these two should be evaluated as a set, and using an `AND` between that set and the `[Request ID]` portion keeps it at the same precedence level.

Comment: While your code does solve the problem, the statement "AND takes precedence over OR" is either ambiguous or plain incorrect.

Comment: @Tab Alleman How so? Seems correct and unambiguous to me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190276.aspx

Comment: @pabrams Thanks, was just looking for that!

Comment: @TabAlleman, NO, that's not true at all. AND does have higher precedence over OR in all form of language.

Comment: If AND takes precedence over OR, then parenthesis should not be needed, because both sides of the AND would have to be true, and the issue that the OP saw would not occur.   At least that is what that statement says to me.   If it really means something else, then it is by definition ambiguous.

Comment: @TabAlleman The parentheses are needed because AND takes precedence over OR.

Comment: Well then the statement is ambiguous, because the way I read it, the opposite is implied.   And I read the article in the link, and it does not illuminate the meaning of precedence.

Comment: @TabAlleman By `AND` having a higher precedence over `OR`, all of the `AND` statements are evaluated first, *then* the `OR` statements would be evaluated.  In the OP's case, he wants both the `[Project Name]` and `[Originator]` `WHERE` statements to be evaluated as a set.  The only way to do that would be to couple them in a single `AND` statement.

Comment: @TabAlleman, OP is doing `cond1 AND cond2 OR cond3` thus due to precedence it will be evaluated as `cond1 AND cond2 followed by OR cond3`

Comment: Fine I understand now how the statement was intended.   Here is the ambiguity, to someone who has never had "precedence" explained in this context:   "AND has higher precedence" = "AND is more important, and therefore is evaluated LAST, to ensure that it is met, regardless of the lower-precedent operators".

Comment: From Dictionary.com:   Precedence, noun.   the right to precede in order, rank, or importance; priority.   So yes, in plain English, Precedence = importance.

Comment: @TabAlleman, unfortunately here it doesn't mean same rather it means precedes other operator in terms of evaluation.

Comment: @TabAlleman that contradicts your own assertion that the most important is evaluated last.

Comment: Not at all.  When speaking of filters, the most important filter would have to be evaluated last to make sure that its evaluation is not over-ridden by any other evaluations that follow.   If "And" is more important than "Or", then both sides of the AND would have to be true, regardless of whether the outer side of the OR is true.

Comment: @Rahul you, sir, are correct.   Siyual was using a narrow context-sensitive meaning of the word "precedence" making his statement correct if one knows the contextual meaning of the word, but to an English-speaker who does not know the Microsoft-Specific usage of that word in this context, the statement is ambiguous at best.

Comment: And @pabrams at this point, I can only conclude that you are being deliberately dense for the sake of prolonging a futile argument.

Comment: @TabAlleman I can only assume that you are being accidentally dense.  This is by no means Microsoft-specific. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: @TabAlleman Perhaps *operator order-of-operations* would have been a more descriptive name (as tautological and redundant as it may be), but Microsoft chose *operator precedence*, and there's not much we can do to change that.  Other than putting in a ticket that they'll sit on for 6 years and eventually close without doing anything.

Comment: Again, the way the word precedence is used in this context is not specific to Microsoft. Just because one thing precedes another does NOT mean it's more important.

Comment: @TabAlleman And yes, that (precedence != importance) applies to plain English as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman - operator precedence is a standard industry term. A few examples that have nothing to do with Microsoft. [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/sql-precedence.html)  [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/operator.htm#997691) [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @MartinSmith yes yes, but whether you call it a Microsoft term or standard industry term is tangential and talks past my point, rather than refuting it.   There IS a Plain English definition of Precedence which I *cited* that explains why the ambiguity I referred to exists.

Comment: @TabAlleman - This is a site for programmers. There's nothing wrong with using the standard term. At worst it will educate.

Comment: Nobody's saying anybody did anything wrong (Well, I'm not).   I stated that something was ambiguous.  Somebody explained what that something meant, and cited supporting documentation.   I explained how the statement *could* be taken another way and cited supporting documentation.   I'm not attacking anyone anymore, only explaining the reason for my first statement.   And yes, some amount of education most certainly has taken place here.

Answer (score 4):

Group your `WHERE` conditions by parenthesizing them like below

```
WHERE [Request ID] IS NOT NULL
AND 
([Project Name] LIKE @ProjectName + '%'
OR [Originator] LIKE @Originator + '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

Read up on operator precedence (the and/or precedence applies to most languages and mathematics, not just SQL)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190276.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations